# Is there a way to get some notification if my ubuntu 12.04 uses 90% of CPU

Tags: 12.04, cpu

Now a days, My computer is getting stuck as I m running lot of programs.What I need is a some kind of notification when processes become 90% or so.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the [**CPU frequency scaling indicator** [image: Install indicator-cpufreq]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/indicator-cpufreq/). This will install an icon in the appmenu, here you can click and toggle your CPU to more conservative settings; see if this helps.

Or you can try [**Psensor** [image: Install psensor]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/psensor/) - a graphical temperature monitor for Linux